# Using AWK to split elements separated by " "

Tags: csv, awk, delimiter

I have a .csv file which contains three elements that I want to further separate. The rows in the file look like this:

```
gene_id "ENSDARG00000104632", gene_version "2", gene_name "RERG"
gene_id "ENSDARG00000104632", gene_version "2", transcript_id "ENSDART00000166186"
gene_id "ENSDARG00000104632", gene_version "2", transcript_id "ENSDART00000166186"
```

I want to take the strings in " " and make them into their own elements separated by ,

Basically I want it to look like this:

```
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, gene_name, RERG
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
```

I had thought to do it like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=",";FS="""};{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
```

However, it seems AWK cannot recognize " as a delimiter. Does anyone have a recommendation as to how to achieve this?

Comment: No tool or programming language can recognize any given character within any text delimited by that character. You always need to escape it or handle it otherwise: `"\""` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[ ",]+' -v OFS=', ' '{sub(/"$/,""); $1=$1} 1' file
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, gene_name, RERG
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
gene_id, ENSDARG00000104632, gene_version, 2, transcript_id, ENSDART00000166186
```

Comment: Only in some awks. What `NF--` does is undefined behavior per POSIX.

Comment: Thanks! I don't fully understand, but it definitely worked.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to ask questions if there's any part of it that's unclear.